# Scan transfers of token on ethereum using web3.py

Tags: web3js, etherscan, web3.py, python, transfer

I am trying getting specific token transfers value using web3.py library. I succeeded getting all transactions where in the transaction there is the token transferred.
My problem is that the value that i am getting using "event: Transfer(from,to,value)" is the sum of all the transfers in the same transaction. any way to get the data as presented in etherscan.com?

[image]

Any other recommended way to do it?